# How to write a "Between" Query Expression for today's date and two date attributes on an entity in a single condition?

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a "new_Term" entity with a "new_StartDate" and "new_EndDate" attributes.  I effectively want to write this statement in a single Query Expression:

```
new_StartDate <= DateTime.UtcNow <= new_EndDate
```

My first idea would be to use the Between ConditionOperator, but the between operator only works on a single attribute, ie:

```
// Not valid because the first parameter expects a string attribute name, not a value
new ConditionExpression(DateTime.UtcNow.Date, ConditionOperator.Between, "new_startdate", "new_enddate")
```

Besides the obvious two Condition Expressions, is there a way to do it in a single Condition Expression?

```
new ConditionExpression("new_startdate", ConditionOperator.LessEqual, DateTime.UtcNow);
new ConditionExpression("new_enddate", ConditionOperator.GreaterEqual, DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that you have the best of all possible answers at the bottom of your question:

```
new ConditionExpression("new_startdate", ConditionOperator.LessEqual, DateTime.UtcNow);
new ConditionExpression("new_enddate", ConditionOperator.GreaterEqual, DateTime.UtcNow);
```

The ConditionOperator enumeration is the limiting factor -- whether you write fetchXml or use queryexpression you are stuck with the [conidition operators available in this enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.query.conditionoperator.aspx). And as you rightly pointed out, between doesn't take the parameters you would need.

Your only other supported (on-premise only) option to further reduce that statement is use SQL to access the filter views but that is certainly overkill :)

Comment: I think you're right Ben.  The Condition Expression allows a params array of values, but now way of specifying a params array of attributes.  I could add an extension method to the Filter Expression though.  filterExpression.AttributesBetween("new_startdate", "newenddate", DateTime.UtcNow), which would add the two Condition Expressions one at a time to the Filter Expression.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it in FetchXML?  You might be able to do it and then use **FetchXmlToQueryExpressionRequest** to run the query.  I wrote [a blog post that has an example awhile back](http://edgewaters.blogspot.com/2010/12/two-ways-to-build-crm-queryexpression.html).

Comment: I think this would be a case of the cure being worse than the disease.

Answer (score 1):

```
QE.Criteria.AddCondition("modifiedon",  ConditionOperator.Between, new Object[] {
                first,
                last});
```

This works for me. the variables first and last are type DateTime.

Comment: Reread the question.  I don't want to pass in two dates and a field, I want to pass in two fields and a date.